# In Eclipse, can I make Open With In-Place Editor the default option?

Tags: eclipse, excel, default, in-place-editor

I need to spend a lot of time manipulating ridiculous amounts of Excel data and often find myself with a dozen or more Excel workbooks open in several different instances of Excel, making it very difficult to find the worksheet I want at any given time.

I came to the realization that I could tone down this madness by using Eclipse by opening the both excel files and csv files with the "In-Place" editor.

However, I can't figure out how to make the in-place editor the default editor.  Any ideas?

(Alternatively, is there a way I can add a file-explorer panel and tabs to excel to give it similar functionality.)

Answer (score 6):

You can go to Window->Preferences->Editors->File Associations and associate *.csv file with the Text Editor. Then set it as the default editor. Unfortunately it seems just clicking the csv file does not open it. Selecting the file and clicking F3 works though.

Comment: worked fine for me (I can open the *.csv files in the Text-Editor by simply double clicking on them). thanks

Comment: I would not recommend associating the built in text editor with .xls files.  All that will do is open a binary file inside an Eclipse text tab and that isn't human readable.    The solution to this question WILL allow you to edit an Excel file within a Eclipse tab without opening the excel file in a separate window.  I've seen it.  It works on most peoples systems.

Comment: @ganime OP question is related to excel files but your answer seems related csv files.

Comment: @mannedear, the OP says "by opening the both excel files and csv files with the "In-Place" editor" hence my answer about the csv files. Anyway, it is the same for Excel files or any other file: You can associate it with the corresponding editor.

Answer (score 0):

In [Eclipse documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tips/platform_tips.html) you can find a hint how to prevent in-place OLE editors (search for "prevent" on the page), which is quite the opposite what you wanted, isn't it?

By any chance do you have the "Allow in-place system editors" option turned off in Windows | Preferences | General | Editors ? If so, please turn it on. I don't have high hopes for this, because the option seems to be on by default, so you might have it already set.

Comment: The in-place OLE editors -- which I most definitely want -- are on -- which is as I want it; I just can't figure out how to make them the default.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, I don't know that it can help you but try to change encoding to UTF-8:Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> TextEditors -> Spelling. I change that and it works.